# Syntax error insert "}" to complete classBody, new at coding

Tags: java, syntax

I have looked around and could not seem to find a solution to this. I'm not sure what is wrong with my code here. Link to my code http://pastebin.com/8z7rjVVK

Error received while compiling:

```
    ===== COMPILING - PLEASE WAIT... =====
src\server\model\players\packets\ClickingButtons.java:1313: error: reached end o
f file while parsing
}
 ^
1 error
=============== DONE ===================
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Sorry, I know there are other questions regarding the same error, but I can't seem to fix this. Thanks. This is Java.

Comment: Please tell us more about the language you are using

Comment: I think you may also need to share a larger snippet of your code. This looks like some version of C, and it looks like you are using a switch statement, and if I'm correct, then what does the switch statement look like?

Comment: Java. And my code is extremely long. The matching bracket is very far up.

Comment: Its in Java, its in the last sentence :)

Comment: I can put the entire code in if you would like to see. Editing now.

Comment: You could perhaps post the entire code on another website that hosts code snippets; SO usually frowns on overly large code segments. But if this is an issue of just a missing brace, all I can say is to comb through the relevant code line by line to make sure every `{` is matched by a `}`.

Comment: I cut down the code a lot because it was just really long. I'm not sure if it is just a case of a missing bracket because everything was fine until I put the last bit of code in. (case 82024 and 82020)

Comment: Pretty sure it's a missing `}` like the error says. Put it in an IDE. Reformat it. Chances are that will find your error.

Comment: I'm currently using Eclipse. All it seems to tell me is the syntax error.

Comment: consider refactoring your code a bit

Comment: "pastebin.com" is a decent place to put the code and then link it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8z7rjVVK @SeanDuggan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (or at least one of them) is that you have an `if` statement inside a `switch` block. It's almost at the end of the code:

```
if (c.isAutoButton(actionButtonId))
    c.assignAutocast(actionButtonId);
```

You can't have code directly as a "child" of a `switch` statement, it must be placed inside a `case` block.

Comment: I had already seen it. I still think that the problem is the `if` statement - lines 1295 and 1296

Comment: What do you suggest I do?

Comment: That depends on what the code is supposed to do... My guess is that originally the two lines were outside the `switch`, then you started coding the two additional cases 82024 and 82020, and unadvertedly placed them under the `if` block. If that's what happened, then you should move the `if` block to the end again, just over `} //This is the last bracket, with the error.`.

Comment: I tried adding another bracket, but it turns that if statement into unreachable code?

Comment: The big question is, where do you expect that "if" statement to execute?

Comment: case 24017 @SeanDuggan

Comment: Then your answer is simple. Move it before the break statement above.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Wow, that fixed it. Thanks a lot. Sorry for being such an idiot, haha.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it, you define the switch statement and open it with a `{`, but then you never close it off.

```
switch (actionButtonId) {
    case 118098:
```

So I added an extra `}` close bracket at the end of the whole class and the only errors I'm left with are ones for the missing classes. (I don't have your server directory classes)

I would advise using an IDE (like eclipse) or rewriting this class to use an individual method for each case.

Also, using `{ }` for `if-else` statements will help avoid this type of issue in the future.

*EDIT: Final Solution*

Once you've got the final close bracket in place, you also needed to move the if statement above the break key word.

The following if statement (around line 1285) became unreachable once the final close bracket was in place

```
    break;

    if (c.isAutoButton(actionButtonId))
        c.assignAutocast(actionButtonId);
```

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, and when I add another bracket on the end, it says my if statement becomes unreachable code.

Comment: Then your code must be different to what you pasted in the link. I've copied from the link, pasted it into a class in eclipse and added the closing curly brace. The errors I have left are for missing classes, like I say.

Comment: Could you paste your code into a pastebin for me? That would help a lot.

Comment: It's strange, the missing classes problem doesn't happen for my class, only for the one I got from you. However, yours has the problem fixed. So yours sparked another bunch of errors but corrected this one. Did you change anything besides that ending bracket?

Comment: I only added the ending bracket. My eclipse is configured to format and add the final keyword where appropriate on its save actions, so that will have happened too. But the missing classes errors in mine are only because I don't have you Server package classes. (I'm filling it in with dummy ones now to see if they're blocking the errors you're seeing)

Comment: Thank you for doing that. Let me know what happens next.

Comment: Ah, look at that, I'm slightly late to the party. Yes I did get the error about the if statement being unreachable, but as the accepted answer says in the comments, you needed to move it above the break statement.